# Insert client input into MySQL database with C

Tags: mysql, sql, c

How do I write a C program which gets the client input for MySQL server? I'm using Fedora as my OS.

Here is my code:

```
#include<my_global.h>
#include<mysql.h>

main()
{
    char name[25];
    MYSQL *conn;
    conn=mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","","testdb",0,NULL,0);
    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    mysql_query(conn,"CREATE TABLE Users(name VARCHAR(25))");

    mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO Users VALUES(name)");
    //mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO Users VALUES('Farhan')");
    //mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO Users VALUES('Dileep')");
    //mysql_query(conn,"INSERT INTO Users VALUES('RAJIV')");

    mysql_close(conn);
}
```

I want the client input to be stored in MySQL database and not the constant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sprintf'ing the name into your query, something like this:

```
int len = query_len + name_len + 1;
char * insert_query = (char *) malloc(len);
snprintf(insert_query, len, "INSERT INTO Users VALUES('%s')", name);
```

However, you'll need to take some care when checking the buffer lengths and especially [escaping the name string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html).