# Insert variable value into a mysql table

Tags: mysql, c

The following function reads the buffer from an external machine, with strtok I get some tokens which I need and in printf I have some results like

```
Results1: 12, 23.345, 2.34, 23.45, 5.67
```

I want to save these results in a Mysql table called results but I don't know what to write inside the VALUES() in my query. How can I insert resa, resb, resc, resd, rese?

```
for (;;)
{
 char buff[1000];

 n=read(fd,buff,1000);
 sleep(1);

 char resa[25] = "", resb[25] = "", resc[25] = "", resd[25] = "", rese[25] = "";
 char* ptr;

 ptr = strtok(buff, "+PARAMETERS()\nsYSTEM ,=M:DK:RT:PTT()");
 int i = 0;
 while (ptr != NULL)
 {
    ptr = strtok(NULL, "+PARAMETERS()\nsYSTEM ,=M:DK:RT:PTT()");
    if (i == 2)
        strcat(resa, ptr); 
    if (i == 5)
        strcat(resb, ptr); 
    if (i == 6)
        strcat(resc, ptr); 
    if (i == 8)
        strcat(resd, ptr); 
    if (i == 10)
        strcat(rese, ptr); 
    i++;
   }

   printf("Results1: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n\n", resa,resb,resc,resd,rese);

 if(mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO results VALUES(...)"))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    return -1;
}

res = mysql_use_result(conn);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate (?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210506/insert-client-input-into-mysql-database-with-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query

```
INSERT INTO results("resa","resb","resc","resd","rese") VALUES(resa,resb,resc,resd,rese)
```

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO results VALUES(resa,resb,resc,resd,rese)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use `sprintf()` to print into a character array, like you use `printf()` to print to `stdout`.

```
char querystring[256];
size_t sizeQuerystring = sizeof querystring;

if (sizeQuerystring < snprintf(querystring, sizeQuerystring,
  "INSERT INTO results (resa, resb, resc, resd, rese)" \
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
  resa, resb, resc, resd, rese))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "The query string to small.\n");
}
else
{
  ... /* issue query */
}
```

You need to take care to not overflow the target array though. `snprintf()` helps to do this programmatically.

---

If using GCC you can use `asprintf()`, which allocates as many entries to the character array as needed. The array needs be `free()`ed afterwards.

```
char * pquerystring = NULL;

if (-1 == asprintf(&pquerystring, 
  "INSERT INTO results (resa, resb, resc, resd, rese)" \
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
  resa, resb, resc, resd, rese))
{
  perror("asprintf() failed");
}
else
{
  ... /* issue query */
}

free(pquerystring);
```

As `asprintf()` is an extension to the C Standard using it breaks the code's portability.

Comment: is the `\` required? It worked whether I had it or not. https://ideone.com/A3aNsJ    https://ideone.com/P1UQL9

Comment: @cokedude: No, it's not. It's just a habit to always initialise variables.

Comment: Sorry there was supposed to be a backslash in the back ticks. Not sure why it didn't show up. Is the backslash between the quoted strings on separate lines required?

Comment: You apparently have to do a double backslash in back ticks if you want them to show up in a code block. Never knew that.

Comment: @cokedude: The backslash is also not necessary. Above it just explicitly indicates that the two string on the two line shall be taken as being on one line and with be one string.

Answer (score 0):

use like this.

```
 if(!mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)VALUES (value)")) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return -1;
    }

    res = mysql_use_result(conn);
```